# Informatica - Greenplum Database Target - Increase throughput. Additional setting required in ODBC.ini file for increasing throughput

Tags: informatica, greenplum, throughput

For a request in informatica, where we need to load data from SQL Server(Source) to Postgresql Greenplum Database(Target).  Noticed throughput is 35(rows/second).

One additional change was made in the odbc.ini file, then the throughput jumped to 1500(rows/second).

Please add the BatchMechanism=2 as below, the issue is solved

```
Driver=******/ODBC7.1/lib/DWgplm27.so
Description=DataDirect 7.1 PostgreSQL Wire Protocol
AlternateServers=
ApplicationUsingThreads=1
***BatchMechanism=2***
```

Hope, it will help others too.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You should be using the Greenplum Wire Protocol with Greenplum. 1500 rows/second is very slow.